# Extracting Date/Time from comment cell

Tags: vba, excel, date, excel-formula

I have a comment field with cells containing text like this:

```
Cancelled by user at 2018-01-03 03:11:57 without charge
```

I want to get the date and time information, but it may not always be in the 3rd/4th from last spaces, otherwise I might try to do some sort of complicated split of the cell. Is there an "in cell" way extract the date time information? Or will this need a VBA script? I prefer the former, but I'm trying to make a macro to simplify my life anyway, so VBA would work too.

Comment: Assuming: a-the date format is always the same, b-dates always 21st century and c-preceding text won't contain "20", the following would retrieve the date-time from cell A1 - `=MID(A1,FIND("20",A1),19)`

Comment: @CLR True, as long as `"20"` doesn't exist anywhere in the string before the date, and as long as the date string consists of exactly 19 characters. This may fit the OP's needs.

Comment: Ah, i like it. But I don't think I can guarantee the preceding text doesn't have "20" in it. Where it says "user" would be an e-mail address that's typically name.# (omitted here for obvious reasons). But, if the match could be to the first 2 letters of a word, and not just the first "20", it could work.

Comment: @VioChemist Is your date format always the same (i.e. exactly 19 characters long)?

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 Yes, the date format should be the same.

Comment: Okay, perhaps `=MID(A1,FIND("at 20",A1)+3,19)` would be better. This would require the email address to contain `at 20` to be a problem which seems unlikely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd propose the following formula:

`=MID(A1,FIND("at 20",A1)+3,19)`

This would require that the date is always preceded by the word 'at' and the date string starts with 20.

Comment: I like this better than my answer. Simpler, assuming it fits the OP's needs. Actually you could even do `= IFERROR(<your formula>,MID(A1,FIND("at 19"...` to accommodate for those years starting with 19.

Comment: For my specific purpose, I think this is the easiest, thanks! Otherwise I like the general solution that @ImaginaryHuman072889 proposed

Answer (score 2):

You can try this function. It splits the string checking for items that have the first letter numeric, and builds a result string of just the date information.

```
Public Function ParseForDate(sCell As String) As String
  Dim vSplit As Variant
  Dim nIndex As Integer
  Dim sResult As String

  vSplit = Split(sCell, " ")
  For nIndex = 0 To UBound(vSplit)
    If IsNumeric(Left$(vSplit(nIndex), 1)) Then
      sResult = sResult & vSplit(nIndex) & " "
    End If
  Next
  ParseForDate = Trim$(sResult)
End Function
```

If you wanted to use it in a formula it would look something like this:

```
=ParseForDate(A1)
```

To use it in a VBA routine:

```
Dim s as String
s = ParseForDate(Range("A1"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Non-VBA solution: (this is assuming the date format is always the same for all cells)

```
= MAX(IFERROR(DATEVALUE(MID(A1,ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,LEN(A1)-19)),20)),0))
 +MAX(IFERROR(TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,LEN(A1)-19)),20)),0))
```

Note this is an array formula, so you must press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd> when typing this formula.

You will obviously then need to format the cell as a date and time, but this formula gets the numerical value that Excel uses for its internal date and time system.

Comment: Nice use of `INDEX()`

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using a regex will enable you to fetch the date and time, **irrespective of its placement in the string**. The following solution will work if the date and time are of the same format as shown in the example string.

**Code:**

```
Sub getDateTime()
    Dim objReg, matches, str
    str = Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value                'Change this as per your requirements
    Set objReg = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    objReg.Global = True
    objReg.Pattern = "\d{4}(?:-\d{2}){2}\s*\d{2}(?::\d{2}){2}"
    If objReg.test(str) Then
        Set matches = objReg.Execute(str)
        strResult = matches.Item(0)
        MsgBox strResult
    End If
End Sub
```

---

[**Click for Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/TdBhU6/2)

**Regex Explanation:**

- `\d{4}` - matches 4 digits representing the year
- `(?:-\d{2}){2}` - matches `-` followed by 2 digits. `{2}` in the end repeats this match 2 times. Once for getting `MM` and the next time for `DD`
- `\s*` - matches 0+ whitespaces to match the space between the Date and Time
- `\d{2}` - matches 2 digits representing the `HH`
- `(?::\d{2}){2}` - matches `:` followed by 2 digits. The `{2}` in the end repeats this match 2 times. First time for matching the `:MM` and the next time for matching the `:SS`

---

**Screenshots:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This will be good for about 90 years *(using cell **C3** for example)*:

```
Sub GetDate()
    Dim s As String
    s = Range("C3").Comment.Text
    arr = Split(s, " ")
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If Left(arr(i), 2) = "20" Then
            msg = arr(i) & " " & arr(i + 1)
            MsgBox msg
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]